# Validating a JSON post request coming into a python flask app

Tags: python, json, curl, flask

I have a simple flask app

```
@app.route("/endpoint/", methods=['POST'])
def mypostmethod():

    if 'Content-Type' in request.headers and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':

        post_data = request.json

        req_data = request.get_json()

        content = req_data['content']

        return content
```

and I curl as follows:

> curl -X POST "localhost:8080/endpoint/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{'content': 'Blah'}'

I get the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)</p>
```

It is because, json body in cURL is using single quotes, when I use double quotes it works.

**I was wondering, how can I add some code in my flask app to check this error and return a custom response code and some response message? Where do I add the try block? Can you please use my code as example.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with JSONs, but I would try something like this:

Data you got are (I guess) in `request.json`.

As this is error you got - `Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`, I would maybe do

```py
include json

try:
 json.dumps(request.json)
except JSONDecodeError as e:
 return("wrong request data")
```

`JSONDecodeError` is mentioned in `json` library documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: My mistake, meant `json.dumps` :)

Answer (score -2):

Use double quotes in your json:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:8080/endpoint/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"content": "Blah"}'
```

Comment: Hi, I know that. My question was how to add code to flask app to catch this and return a custom response error/code.

Answer (score -2):

This is simply not a valid argument for the -d option in cURL. You need to replace the single quotes with the double quotes in the argument and enclose it with single quotes.

```
wrong: '{'content': 'Blah'}'
ok:    '{"content": "Blah"}'
```

Comment: Hi, I know that. My question was how to add code to flask app to catch this and return a custom response error/code.